# Why does this program receive a SEGV?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, gnu-assembler

I have the following program, which (I think) allocates a bunch of virtual memory (by changing the system break with sys_brk), and then attempts to write to the newly allocated memory. However, I am receiving a SIGSEGV (on the very first memory write, and I don't understand why).

```
[OP@localhost sys_brk]$ cat out_of_memory.s 
    .section .text
    .globl _start

_start:
    mov $12, %rax
    mov $0x1000000, %rdi
    syscall


    # i: index of memory we are writing to (%rax)
    mov $0x403000, %rax
evil_loop_start:
    cmp $0x1000000, %rax
    jge evil_loop_end

    mov %rax, (%rax)
    add 0x8, %rax
    jmp evil_loop_start
evil_loop_end:
    hlt
```

Comment: call sys_brk with the value of 0 to get the current brk in RAX. Add the amount of extra space you want to RAX and then call sys_brk again with the value as a parameter.

Comment: You also need to use `add $0x8, %rax` to add 8 to rax. You forgot the `$` for an immediate value. HLT will segfault as well. You should use sys_exit syscall

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks. Why does HLT segfault?

Comment: [HLT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/hlt) is a privileged instruction and can't be run in user mode (ring 3). It can only be used in the kernel (ring 0) or real mode.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was under the impression that segfault occurred when a program attempted an invalid memory access.

Comment: @MichaelPetch BTW, I fixed everything you mentioned, but another, rather bizarre error appeared. The program now segfaults when running normally, but *not* in gdb.

Comment: Using privileged instruction will also raise #GP  (general protection fault).I linked to the HLT documentation in my previous comment.

Comment: Without seeing the code I can't speculate. Does this work:     .`section .text`
    .`globl _start`

`_start:`
    `mov $12, %rax`
    `mov $0, %rdi`
    `syscall`
    `add $0x1000000, %rax`
    `mov %rax, %rdi`
    `mov $12, %rax`
    `syscall`
    `mov $0x403000, %rax`
`evil_loop_start:`
    `cmp $0x1000000, %rax`
    `jge evil_loop_end`

    `mov %rax, (%rax)`
    `add $0x8, %rax`
    `jmp evil_loop_start`
`evil_loop_end:`
    `mov %rax, %rdi`
    `mov $60, %rax`
    `syscall`

Comment: Linux delivers SIGSEGV when user-space programs try to use privileged instructions.  POSIX says it *should* deliver SIGILL with a  `ILL_PRVOPC` as part of the siginfo.  [How can I tell whether SIGILL originated from an illegal instruction or from kill -ILL?](//stackoverflow.com/q/17367111), but that's not what Linux does.